# j2me error: class myClass is public should be declared in a file named myClass.java

Tags: java, java-me

Guys, how can I correct the error above, my class name does have the extension.java. I am new to j2me and I need to do a location based application but I am struggling so hard...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java)

Answer (score 4):

Generally in Java, each .java file can contain at most one public top-level class, and the file has to have the same name as this class.
So a class called `MyClass` *must* be stored in a file called `MyClass.java`!

NB: Class names should start with a capital letter

**Update:** when using packages (the `package` instruction at the beginning of the java file), the file must be stored in a directory structure identical to the package structure.
So if you have this file:

```
package com.something.test;
public class MyClass {}
```

it must be stored in `{root}/com/something/test/MyClass.java` and compiled with
`javac com.something.test.MyClass`
relative from the directory `{root}`

Comment: Can you help me by saying how to I actually fix the proble, how do I actually create a myclass.java cos I created a midlet.java and what should I put inside the class.java and midlet.java, what's the difference, I am using netbeans, I am new to it, my professor only gaves us lecture no workshop, he told us to research on our own and do the project, but it is quite trick as I had never used netbeans before and we had no exercises on this so I am quite lost, if you can help me to solve the problem, I still have it. Thank you for your time

Comment: Well, I have never worked with netbeans, so I can give you any specific hints... You should have a project explorer where all the source files are, and there you have a file called `MyClass.java`. When you open it, one of the first lines should be `public class MyClass`. These names must match!
For more info check this: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javame/quickstart.html

Answer (score 2):

In NetBeans 6.5, I fixed this problem by following the first paths on the left down to:

fileName  >    Source Packages  >        filename  >            Main.java

Right-click on Main.java, move the mouse over Refactor, then click Rename.  Type the class name there (it IS case-sensitive) and select Refactor.  This should solve the problem.