# Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program, but I'm getting this compiler error:

```
Main.java:1: error: class WeatherArray is public, should be declared in a file named WeatherArray.java
public class WeatherArray {
       ^
1 error
```

I have checked my file names, and my public class is the same as my .java file.

How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class WeatherArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It says its trying to compile `Main.java` not the `WeatherArray.java`

Comment: I am on Mac OSX using eclipse.

Comment: 1. be sure your filename respects the case of the class name;

2. get rid of all the nested `while` loops, or I will kill a lot of kittens tonight.

Comment: What command does Eclipse execute to get the above error?

Comment: I used ideone.com to get the error

Comment: man you have to create new class using RMB src-new-newClass

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Name of public class must match the name of **.java** file in which it is placed (like `public class Foo{}` must be placed in `Foo.java` file). So either:

- rename your *file* from `Main.java` to `WeatherArray.java`
- rename the *class* from `public class WeatherArray {` to `public class Main {`

Comment: Where would Main.java be located in the file structure?

Comment: If you don't have a `public class Main` there is no `Main.java`. Don't confuse a main class with a `main` method. Your `main` method is in `WeatherArray.java`. Also, I think your nested while's should be sequential `if` statements.

Comment: Ok thank you that helped a lot. I will defiantly remove all the nested while loops.

Comment: It could also work to make the class non-public by removing `public` (but this would cause some issues if you're trying to use the class from a different package).

Answer (score 14):

The name of the public class within a file has to be the same as the name of that file.

So if your file declares class WeatherArray, it needs to be named WeatherArray.java

Answer (score 5):

This happens when you have 1 name for the Java class on hard disk and another name of Java class in the code!!

For example, I renamed my `MainActivity` class to `MainnActivity` only (!) in the code. I got this error immediately.

There is also a visual indicator in the Project tab of Android Studio - a class inside a class, like you have nested classed, but with an error indicator.

[image]

The solution is to simply rename class name in the Project tab (`SHIFT` + `F6`) to match the name in the Java code.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem but solved it when I realized that I didn't compile it with the correct casing. You may have been doing

> javac Weatherarray.java

when it should have been

> javac WeatherArray.java

Answer (score 2):

You named your file as **Main.java**. name your file as **WeatherArray.java** and compile.

Answer (score 2):

Just experience this issue today. Thanks to viewBinding.

Problem was the autoGenerated binding. I had two xml files

- one_two.xml
- onetwo.xml

**Solution # 1 :** Just use

```
tools:viewBindingIgnore="true"
```

in any one file.

**Solution  # 2 :**

```
Rename the xml file
```

Answer (score 1):

your file is named **Main.java** where it should be

> WeatherArray.java

Answer (score 1):

Yes! When you face these type of problem then try to following points

- Check Your **.java** file name and class name.
- If Class name and public class name are not the same then **RENAME** class name.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I was using syncthing. It created a duplicate that I was not aware of and my compilation was failing.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this error you should follow the following steps:

```
1) You should make a new java class
```

[image: You should make a new java class.]

```
2) Name that class
```

[image: Name that class]

```
3) And a new java class is made
```

[image: And a new java class is made]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error once. It was really funny. I had created a backup of the .java file with different filename but the same class name. And kept on trying to build it till I checked all the files in my folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (using IntelliJ) I copy and pasted and renamed the workspace, and I am still using the old path to compile the new project.

In this case this particular error will happen too, if you have the same error you can check if you have done the similar things.

Answer (score 0):

The terminal is not case sensitive when writing "Javac [x].java", so make sure what you write in the terminal matches the filename and class name.

My class name and file name were both "MainClass", but I was compiling using "Mainclass". Notice I forgot to make the "c" capital.

Answer (score 0):

From Ubuntu command line:

```
//WeatherArray.java
public class WeatherArray {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("....Hello World");
}}
```

> ls

WeatherArray.java

> javac WeatherArray.java
>
> ls

WeatherArray.java  WeatherArray.class

> java WeatherArray

....Hello World

Of course if you name your java file with different name than WeatherArray, you need to take out public and it would be:

```
// Sunny.java
class WeatherArray {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("....Hello World"); }}
// javac Sunny.java; java WeatherArray
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make WeatherArray class from public to default.

**public class WeatherArray**  =====> **class WeatherArray**

then you do not get any error and
you can easily compile your code by just writing

==> **javac any_name_you_assign_to_file.java**

Now a WeatherArray.class will generate.

To run your code you have to use class name

==> **java WeatherArray**

Answer (score 0):

Compile WeatherArray.java instead of Main.java

This error comes if you have not saved your source code with the same name of your public class name.

Answer (score 0):

If your class name is the same as the filename then check that it does not contain any zero width character

I accidentally copied a class name with invisible whitespace which caused this exception

Eclipse was able to build the file and Gradle was not

This can be very confusing

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you don't have two identical -- or
very nearly identical -- files in your res/layout folder.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based on my experience with Kotlin, but probably should also work for Java.

In my resource files I had 2 files : `item_alert_edit.xml` and `item_alertedit.xml`.
The compiler converts these files to .java and for some reason removes the _, so effectively both files will have the same name.
I solved it by **renaming** one of the files to be different and this solved the error for me.
Clean build, etc did not work for me.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is quite simple. It lies in your admin rights. before compiling your java code you need to open the command prompt with run as administrator. then compile your code. no need to change anything in your code. the name of the class need to be the same as the name of the java file.. that's it!!

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that a lack of admin rights can cause this error.

Answer (score -1):

when you named your file **WeatherArray.java**,maybe you have another file on hard disk ,so you can rename **WeatherArray.java** as **ReWeatherArray.java**, then rename **ReWeatherArray.java** as **WeatherArray.java**. it will be ok.

Comment: it is actually a comment

Comment: If there's another file with the same name, it will probably overwrite it or give other errors. If you are trying to compile the new file, the advice given in the other answers is all that's needed - just rename the file or class, if there's another file that prevents renaming it, you obviously need to get it out of the way first.

Answer (score -1):

error example:

```
public class MaainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }
}
```

correct example:just make sure that you written correct name of activity that is"main activity"

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from activity_main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to add anything to the 5 answers posted 2-5 years earlier saying the class name needs to match the file name, especially [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31431242/1711796) which already mentioned a spelling mistake in the class name.