# Class is public, should be declared in a file named .java

Tags: java, class, methods, program-entry-point

I'm having this problem which I'm not sure why it's caused.

**"class Account is public, should be declared in a file named Account.java"**

I have 5 classes in my program, all in the same file and all are public:

- Class called Main which includes the main method
- Class called Account is abstract
- 3 classes Account1, Account2, Account3 which extend the abstract class

I named my file Main.java, and it's giving me this error. Then I named my file Account.java, and I got the same error again.

What should I do?

Comment: Split the classes into multiple files?

Comment: @AlexisC. So should I create 5 files, and put in each one of them a class? Will it work that way? Even considering the abstraction case?

Comment: @azurefrog Thanks. If I changed my classes from public to private, will that affect the program at all?

Comment: Depends on what you want do. The rule is that you must have at most one public class per file (and that the file name must match this public class, if any).

Comment: Split  them into multiple files OR remove public access specifier from the classes. Only keep it for ur Main class.

Comment: @AlexisC.: Well, one public *top-level* class per file. It's an optional rule, too - but one that `javac` enforces.

Comment: @GoodBadandUgly If I remove the public access specifier, what should I replace it with?

Comment: @JavaGaga Nothing.Default access modifier means we do not explicitly declare an access modifier for a class, field, method, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java)

Answer (score 3):

1. There can be only one public class per source code file.
2. If there is a public class in a file, the name of the file must match the name of the public class. For example, a class declared as public class Dog { } must be in a source code file named Dog.java.

You should split up your file into 5 files so that you only have one class per file.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be realy hard to solve, because you already provided the answere. You can't have 2 separated public classes in a single java file. So as suggested: create a file Account.java for your account class. If you keep this class in the same package, there is nothing else you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

I just run into your situation at some time, I just check the website on [oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

the obvious said that in the .java file, all your 5 classes is all top-level, so

> A class may be declared with the modifier public, in which case that class is visible to all classes everywhere. If a class has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)

so you can, of course, place your classes to another .java files, or u can just delete your prefix or modifier of your class, and your code will run, but the class can only accessed within this package!