# what is happening when a class with access modifier public when a java file with file name and class name different

Tags: java, filenames, program-entry-point

I just a wrote a code like this with file name b.java

```
public class a{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Hii");
    }
}
```

it gives error like this

```
error: class a is public, should be declared in a file named a.java
```

if i remove access modifier `public` in front of `class` 
it is running fine.
is there a other solution to achieve i don't want to change the names of class or file name unless there is a **big reason**.

*If so please explain me the reason. why we should give the name of file and name of the class with same name.*

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a class as public, then class name should match the file name.

The reason we define any class as public is to make it accessible from other classes or code in other packages.

This rule of naming file name after its class name makes it easy for the compiler to find the class.

Also in JAVA, we can have only one public class in a file.

Comment: The convention is more as a principle of least surprise for developers, than for the compiler (as you can define non-public class in a differently named file).