# I keep getting an error message for my res folder saying: error: class R is public, should be declared in a file named R.java

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors, mobile-development

I keep getting an error message saying:

> error: class R is public, should be declared in a file named R.java.

What does this mean when the R files are automatically generated? It suddenly began to occur.

These errors seem like they are to do with the automatic res files generated.

Is there a problem with my compiler?

[image: Photo of my Logcat]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java)