# How could I run this simple code in the JDK 8.?

Tags: java, java-8

Can anyone please tell me how to compile this code using JDK 8. I tried but it confusing me over public classes defined in the code. I save the code file with both the names of the public classes but it didn't works. The code is as below:

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Person j;
    j=new Person("John");
    j.setAge(20);
    celebrateBirthday(j);
    System.out.println(j.getAge());
  }

  static void celebrateBirthday(Person p){
    p.setAge(p.getAge() + 1);
  }
}

public class Person{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  Person(String n){
    this.name = n;
  }

  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int a){
    this.age = a;
  }
}
```

The compiler shows the error as follows:

```
C:\Users\soman\Desktop>javac Test.java
Test.java:15: error: class Person is public, should be declared in a file named Person.java
public class Person{
             ^
1 error
```

Note - I'm using JDK(1.8) in 32-bit system.

Comment: You need the main method to able to run the class.

Comment: "with both the names of the public clases". There's just one name here `Test`. What is the other name that you are talking about?

Comment: This file compiles just fine as long as the filename is `Test.java`. Each public class must have its own file, so if there are multiple public classes in the file, you have to move one of them to its own file.

Comment: What is the problem you have when you compile the source code or run the java application? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java

Comment: @OmairMajid I've edited the question, please tell me now what to do.?

Comment: @Progman It didn't helped me. I'd checked 4-5 answers on the link provided by you.

Comment: @somanath41 The solution is to place the `Person` class in a new file called `Person.java`.

Comment: @Progman It worked. Thank you. **Also have another question but don't wanna ask cause I think this site is only for the Programmers, I'm just started to learn and its on my own**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java source file can have only one class declared as public, we cannot put two or more public classes together in a .java file. This is because of the **restriction** that the file name should be same as the name of the public class with .java extension. If we want to multiple classes under consideration are to be declared as public, we have to store them in separate source files and attach the package statement as the first statement in those source files.

In your code you should declare your Person class as

```
public class Test{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    Person j;
    j=new Person("John");
    j.setAge(20);
    celebrateBirthday(j);
    System.out.println(j.getAge());
  }

  static void celebrateBirthday(Person p){
    p.setAge(p.getAge() + 1);
  }
}

 class Person{
  private String name;
  private int age;

  Person(String n){
    this.name = n;
  }

  public int getAge(){
    return age;
  }

  public void setAge(int a){
    this.age = a;
  }
}
```

Or create separate file for Person class

Answer (score 0):

Each **`public`** class need to be in its own separate file named by the class name (this is exactly what the error message means). Thus one file `Test.java` containing the `public class Test` and one name `Person.java` containing the `public class Person`.