# Android View Binding problem ,public class name and and file name is different

Tags: android, android-studio

[screenshot of layout file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYkPQ.png)  [Link of the screen shot click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp2R8.png)

FoodItemBinding.java file is generated by compiler ,  how the public class name  and file name is different here, also i m not able to change it.

Check the Screenshot Attched

```
error: class FoodItemBinding is public, should be declared in a file named FoodItemBinding.java
public final class FoodItemBinding implements ViewBinding {
         ^
```

Comment: clean the project and rebuild it

Comment: i tried , still problem not solved

Comment: public class name is "FoodItemBinding" and it java file name is "FooditemBinding.java",

Comment: Add the screenshot of the name of the layout file

Comment: attached please see it

Comment: can you add the name of the layout file

Comment: one workaround is you copy the content of that file and delete it, and then create a new file with some other name and paste the content there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: class X is public should be declared in a file named X.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java)

Answer (score 5):

Name the layout file food_item.xml instead of fooditem.xml

ViewBinding generates the java file as FooditemBinding but the class is still named FoodItemBinding, hence the issue of class name.

Comment: Please try to give proper explanation of the answer.

Comment: Apologies. His current layout is named fooditem.xml. ViewBinding generates the java file as FooditemBinding but the class is still named FoodItemBinding, hence the issue of class name.