# Have an error connecting android project to firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I was following the instruction that firebase gave. While, I get problem.

I was trying to connect my android project to firebase, then this happens.

> class ActivityLoginBinding is public, should be declared in a file named ActivityLoginBinding.java

and this was the problematic point

public final **class** ActivityLoginBinding implements ViewBinding {

thanks

Comment: refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java

Comment: Can you please explain how is this question related to Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Confirm if the file name in which you have the ActivityLoginBinding is also called ActivityLoginBinding.java

Comment: name of class is ActivityLoginBinding, name of .java file is ActivityLogInBinding, which is different. I tried to edit its name but this file is automatically generated by compiler, so I was unable to edit its name.